# Magento 2.4 sales_order_invoice_grid populate custom column with values

Tags: magento2, csv, sales-invoice

I have added the column `transaction_id` to my `sales_order_invoice_grid`.

Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="transaction_id" xsi:type="string">
                    sales_invoice.transaction_id
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_invoice_grid.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
        <column name="transaction_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Transaction ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

The header of the column appears as expected in the `sales_order_invoice_grid` and also in the CSV export file, which can be generated on this page.
The problem is the values are missing.
[image]

Can anyone say what I am missing or what could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The column in the `sales_invoice_grid` table was missing. Now it is working.

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_invoice_grid" resource="sales" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="transaction_id" length="255" unsigned="false" nullable="true" identity="false"
                comment="Transaction ID"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```